# Nestjs Graphql the mutation/query input dto is empty

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I don't know what I miss but the input for the mutation or the queries is always empty
when I debug seems that the input is empty object

This is my code:

resolver

```
  @Query(() => String)
  async testMutation(@Args('args') args: UpvotePostInput) {
    return args.postId;
  }
```

the dto

```
import { InputType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@InputType()
export class UpvotePostInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  postId: string;
}
```

the empty object
[image]

the error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.testMutation.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "testMutation"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.testMutation.",
            "    at completeValue (/....js:559:13)",
            "    at /.....xecute.js:469:16",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)",
            "    at async Promise.all (index 0)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you think directives syntax doesn't matter?

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to add `@IsNotEmpty()` or `@IsOptional()` decorator to the property:

```js
@InputType()
export class UpdateCarInput extends PartialType(CreateCarInput) {
    @Field(() => Int)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    id: number;
}
```

weird, but this resolve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I investigated this behaviour of nestjs and find out that this happens when use use global validation pipe with **whitelist** property set to true.
I tested this global validation pipe

```js
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      // whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },
    }),
  );
```

for this resolver method

```js
  @Mutation()
  createPost(@Args('input') input: CreatePostInput) {
    return this.postsService.create(input);
  }
```

**CreatePostInput** class is generated with nestjs graphql schema first approach

```js
//graphql.ts file
export class CreatePostInput {
    title: string;
    authorId: number;
}
```

nestjs-cli.json file is configured to use **@nestjs/graphql** plugin

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "@nestjs/graphql",
        "options": {
          "introspectComments": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The **input** object is not an empty object

[image]

Comment: My god, I wasted so much time for this. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yesterday I wasted all my time on this problem. I started searching this morning and your answer came across. You saved my day.

Comment: Actually, it's not a strange behavior. I researched about it after your answer and found that if you applied global validation pipe and the whitelist option to true, then you had to use at least one decorator for that property. Otherwise, it would be ignored.
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

Answer (score -1):

Add deep partial
https://gist.github.com/navix/6c25c15e0a2d3cd0e5bce999e0086fc9

```
@Query(() => String)
async testMutation(@Args('args') args: DeepPartial<UpvotePostInput>) {
  return args.postId;
}
```